# Any halfway decent jdbc wrappers for Scala?

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, wrapper

I'm looking for a stripped down (so NOT like squeryl, or anything that creates typesafe queries where I have to respecify the table just to get some data) wrapper for jdbc.

i'm using scala 2.9 and postgres.

Anyone have success here?

Comment: Curious, what is your opposition to typesafe queries? How do you cast your non-typesafe query results to Scala types? Manually presumably. Anyway, I have not used Squeryl, but am using ScalaQuery with great pleasure. TypeSafe picked up the project; "everyone" will be using it when they launch their LINQ-to-SQL evolution of the project, code named, SIQ. Perhaps a bit more explanation re: your use case for straight jdbc would help deter people like me from suggesting what you appear not to want ;-)

Comment: Here is nearly full list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2318935/298389

Comment: @om-nom-nom Actually, it's not nearly full! :-) I gave up on updating it once the wiki overtook it.

Comment: @virtualeyes, I don't have a problem with typesafe queries. I have a problem with having to define an object that is literally mirroring everything I already have in a pre-existing database so I can do queries. There's nothing wrong with ORM-ish things, but sometimes you really just want to do a query and get your results by iterating and doing things like rs.getString("columnOne"), etc.

Comment: @dave, yah, that's why I asked about the use case.  If you just want to get sh*t done without overhead of mapping tables to code, I can appreciate the straight jdbc approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [Prequel](https://github.com/jpersson/prequel/) successfuly in the past. It is just a JDBC wrapper.

There is also Twitter's [Querulous](https://github.com/twitter/querulous), but due to some crippling bugs I found it unusable (leaking connections). It also brings a huge stash of dependencies.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one. I'm currently running as fast as I can from Querulous.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me about Prequel, it's refreshing to see something restrained and sufficient for a change.